# MySQL: IF conditions in query needed to display output in tabular format

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, which should pull a list of courses from my database (mdl_course.fullname), the names of each student as column headers (mdl_user.username), and the date on which they completed the course (mdl_feedback_value.value):

```
SELECT mdl_course.fullname,
if(mdl_user.username = "luis.arroyo", mdl_feedback_value.value, 'No')
As "Luis Arroyo "

FROM `mdl_course`
inner join mdl_feedback on mdl_feedback.course = mdl_course.id
inner join mdl_feedback_item on mdl_feedback_item.feedback = mdl_feedback.id
inner join mdl_feedback_value on mdl_feedback_value.item = mdl_feedback_item.id
inner join mdl_feedback_completed on mdl_feedback_completed.id = mdl_feedback_value.completed
inner join mdl_user on mdl_user.id = mdl_feedback_completed.userid
WHERE 
(mdl_user.username = "luis.arroyo")
and mdl_feedback_value.value LIKE "%/%/%"
GROUP BY mdl_course.fullname
```

Desired output:

```
Course name      Luis Arroyo       
-----------      -----------       
ECON 101         No                
ECON 112         6/30/2017         
etc. etc.
```

What I need to do is list EVERY course in the database (total of 187) and, at the same time, list the specified users and the dates on which they completed the courses (or display 'No' if they haven't). I'm having trouble with my WHERE and GROUP BY clauses. Selecting individual usernames only returns a partial list of courses. In the above case, I only get 38 results instead of 187 (the courses Luis has completed).

Removing mdl_user.username from the WHERE clause gets me a list of all 187 courses, but Luis's completion dates do not show up. Everything shows up as 'No.'

I don't know how to configure my WHERE and GROUP BY clauses to get my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead `INNER JOIN`

Dont need `GROUP BY`

Need use `COALESCE` to convert `NULL` to `'NO'`

Answer (score 0):

Changing my IF statement to a CASE got me the desired output, along with keeping the GROUP BY clause.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN(mdl_user.username = "luis.arroyo") THEN   mdl_feedback_value.value ELSE NULL END)
As "Luis Arroyo "
```